# B92 protocol Change - Chance of Bob’s successful measurements

Tags: quantum-information

Alice chooses at random between the states:

- |0⟩, representing 0,
- |+⟩, representing 1

Bob chooses at random whether to measure in the: $ {|0⟩,|1⟩} $ basis, or   {|+⟩,|-⟩} basis.

If Bob measures in the $ {|0⟩,|1⟩} $ axis,

- Obtains outcome 0 -> state sent by Alice was |0⟩ or |+⟩ -> Unknown bit
- Obtains outcome 1 -> State sent by Alice was |+⟩ -> bit value 1

If Bob measures in the {|+⟩,|-⟩} basis,

- Obtains outcome + -> State sent by Alice was |+⟩ or |0⟩->    Any bit
- Obtains outcome -> State sent by Alice was |0⟩-> Bit value 0

Thus, the Fraction of Bob’s successful measurements will provide the bit value chosen by Alice is:

- (Chooses {|+⟩,|-⟩} basis $\times$ successful choice ) + (Chooses {|0⟩,|1⟩} basis $\times$ successful choice )
- $(\frac{1}{2} \times \frac{1}{2} ) +(\frac{1}{2} \times \frac{1}{2} ) =0.5$

I was wondering where in my reasoning I went wrong as the answer should be 1/4 for the probability of getting definitive information.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the "paths to success" of definitive information outcomes.

Definitive information outcome 1: Bob measures in $|0\rangle,|1\rangle$, measures 1. This outcome needs to pass three checks.

(1) Chance of Bob choosing this basis: 50%

(2) Chance of Alice sending $|+\rangle $: 50%

(3) Chance of Bob measuring $|1\rangle $ given that Alice sent $|+\rangle$: 50%

Total outcome probability: 1/8. The other outcome has identical logic and also has a 1/8 chance for a sum total of 1/4.

Answer (score 0):

Lets take the first basis. If Bob measures in the $|0>,|1>$ basis, there are two outcomes, $1$ and $0$. If outcome is $1$, state Alice sent is $|+>$, and if outcome is $0$, state is either $|0>$ or $|+>$.

So, there are three options Bob can get.

1. $1$ outcome $\quad \rightarrow \quad$ $|+>$ state with probability $50\%$
2. $0$ outcome $\quad \rightarrow \quad$ $|+>$ state with probability $25\%$
3. $0$ outcome $\quad \rightarrow \quad$ $|0>$ state with probability $25\%$

Only succesful measurement will be the third one because it is the only one where we are sure what state Alice sent.